# Иконка аватара без потери качества

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый День! Столкнулся с проблемой. Существуют ли способы сохранения качества аватара без потери качества изображения? Проблема заключается в том, что при загрузке аватара хорошего качества, в миниатюре он теряет все свойства своего качества. Приведу пример отображения при загрузки фотографии хорошего качества: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подозреваю что проблема заключается в сжатии, но есть ли варианты отключения этого сжатия при загрузке? Ниже приведу мой код:

```js
function setAvatar(evt, id) {
  saveImageToDataStorage("/update-avatar", evt, id, localUser.uid, function() {
    // var avatar = document.getElementById("nav_bar_avatar");
    // avatar.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + STORAGE_url + "/public/users/" + localUser.uid + ".jpg?cache=" +  + (new Date()).getTime() + "')";

    let img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.onerror = function() {
      img.src = "static/assets/foto_placeholder72.svg";
    };
    img.onload = function() {
      let canvas = document.getElementById("nav_bar_avatar");
      var scaledCanvas = scaleAndCropImage(img, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(scaledCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
    img.src = STORAGE_url + "/public/users/" + localUser.uid + ".jpg?cache=" + (new Date()).getTime();
  })
}
```

```html
<td class="itemMenu profile">
  <a href="/profile" class="nav_bar_avatar">
    <canvas id="nav_bar_avatar" height="28" width="28" style=" -webkit-clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%); clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%); height: 100%; width: 100%"></canvas>
  </a>
  {{if eq .Active "editProfile"}}
  <a id="nav_bar_user" href="/profile" class="nav_bar_text current"></a>
  {{else}}
  <a id="nav_bar_user" href="/profile" class="nav_bar_text"></a>
  {{end}}
</td>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем помещать картинку в канвас для дальнейшего сжатия? Вы думаете, так будет меньше нагрузка? Нет, вы все равно скачиванием с сервера картинку, а на канвас задействуется больше мощности браузера. Почему бы просто не помещать картинку в тег IMG, таким образом как вы описали, и не использовать для этого инструменты, не предназначенные для этого.

Comment: Однако при использовании canvas'a могу ли я убрать компрессию изображения посредством JS или другими методами?

Comment: Я не разбираюсь к сожалению в канвас, но повторюсь, использовать его для этих задач, а именно для вывода аватара, при любых обстоятельствах, не лучшая идея. Можете просто попробовать, использовать IMG, может быть такая проблема будет и у этого тега, тогда мы что-то упускаем.